# Problema con funciones - Buscar elemento en un arreglo

Tags: c, funciones

Que tal, muy buen día, he estado empezando a programar, y he tenido un problema con un programa referente a funciones.

Resulta que me piden hacer un programa que almacene elementos en un arreglo, y que posteriormente le pida al usuario ingresar un número para buscarlo en el arreglo. 
Si el número ingresado se encuentra en el arreglo, mostrarlo, y también mostrar la ubicación de ese número.

El programa funciona bien para 4 elementos en el arreglo, pero al momento de ingresar 5 elementos, se presenta un problema, ya que al mostrar la ubicación del número ingresado para su búsqueda en el arreglo, siempre me muestra que se encuentra en la posición 4.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Les anexo el código a continuación.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
void buscarElemento(int a[], int size, int element_Busqueda);

int main()
{
    int n; // Variable que determinará el número de elementos del arreglo.
    int i; // Variable para recorrer el arreglo.
    int elemento;

    int array[n]; // Creamos un arreglo de enteros, el número de elementos del arreglo
              // será el número asignado a la variable 'n'.

    printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos del arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingresa el elemento numero %d del arreglo: ", (i+1) );
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Ingresa el elemento a buscar en el arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&elemento);

    buscarElemento(array, n, elemento);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void buscarElemento(int a[], int size, int element_Busqueda)
{
    int j;
    int b = 0;
    int hold1,hold2;

    while(b == 0)
    {
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(element_Busqueda == a[j])
            {
                hold1 = a[j];
                hold2 = j;
                b=1;
            }
        }
    }

    if(b==1)
    {
    printf("El elemento encontrado es %d y se encuentra en la posicion %d.",hold1,hold2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Señalo esto porque veo que comienzas a programar y utilizas la librería iostream en tu programa de C: Asegúrate que tu archivo de código fuente sea .c y no .cpp ya que cpp es C++

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero que te comento es que tu código no es C simplemente por haber incluído la librería `iostream`, que es propia de C++. Debes eliminar esa librería para que el código sea compilable en C.

```
int n; // 1

int array[n]; // 2
```

1. no asignas un valor a `n`, luego la misma tendrá un valor residual (basura) que no controlas en absoluto.
2. Creas un array con el tamaño dado por `n` (que recordemos no está incializada). ¿Qué sucedería si resulta que `n` tiene un valor negativo? ¿y si `n` valiese 0?

Lo que sucede es que el array se crea en el mismo momento que lo declaras, por mucho que después cambies el valor de `n`, el arreglo ya está creado y permanecerá inamovible.

Para solucionar este problema puedes optar por:

1. Crear el array una vez hayas inicializado `n` (esta solución no es compatible con C++):

   ```
   int n; // Variable que determinará el número de elementos del arreglo.

   printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos del arreglo: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   int array[n]; // Creamos un arreglo de enteros, el número de elementos del arreglo
                 // será el número asignado a la variable 'n'.
   ```
2. Crear un arreglo de un tamaño lo suficientemente grande como para garantizar que no va a fallar (esta solución solo es aplicable si el rango de valores posible está limitado):

   ```
   int n; // Variable que determinará el número de elementos del arreglo.

   int array[50]; // Creamos un arreglo de 50 enteros.

   printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos del arreglo: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   ```
3. Usas memoria dinámica. La gran ventaja de usar memoria dinámica es que puedes redimensionar el arreglo a tu antojo, la desventaja es que tienes que gestionar correctamente la memoria para evitar fugas de memoria:

   ```
   int n; // Variable que determinará el número de elementos del arreglo.

   printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos del arreglo: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   int *array = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int)); // Creamos un arreglo de enteros, el número de elementos del arreglo
                 // será el número asignado a la variable 'n'.

   // ...

   free(array); // Liberamos la memoria reservada con malloc
   ```

Más cosillas:

```
while(b == 0)
{
    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if(element_Busqueda == a[j])
        {
            hold1 = a[j];
            hold2 = j;
            b=1;
        }
    }
}
```

¿Qué sucede si intentas encontrar un elemento que no existe en el arreglo? Que entrarás en un bucle sin fin ya que `b` **siempre** valdrá 0.

¿Qué sucede si el elemento está duplicado? Devolverás la posición correspondiente a la última aparición.

El problema del bucle sin fin se produce porque tienes dos bucles anidados. La solución pasa por eliminar el bucle `while` y para ello tienes, básicamente, dos opciones:

1. Usar `break` para salir del bucle (otra ventaja es que te ahorras la variable `b`:

   ```
   for(j=0; j<size; j++)
   {
       if(element_Busqueda == a[j])
       {
           hold1 = a[j];
           hold2 = j;
           break;
       }
   }

   if(j<size)
   {
       printf("El elemento encontrado es %d y se encuentra en la posicion %d.",hold1,hold2);
   }
   ```
2. Modificar la condición del `for` para que sea compuesta:

   ```
   for(j=0; j<size && b==0; j++)
   {
       if(element_Busqueda == a[j])
       {
           hold1 = a[j];
           hold2 = j;
           b=1;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunas partes que son incorrecta en tu aplicación:

- `int array[n]`: estás declarando el array, pero no has inicializado la variable `n`, por lo que tendrá un valor no determinado, la forma correcta es crear la matriz despues de inicializar el valor de `n`
- La implementación de `buscarElemento` puede ser mejorada, no es necesario el `while` ni la variable `b` que utilizas como bandera, entiendo que la función encuentra el primer elemento que tenga un valor igual al que le pasas como parámetro, por lo que debería terminar cuando pase ello, lo mejor es retornar la función en ese momento( `return`).

Corrigiendo tu programa con las recomendaciones anteriores te muestro el siguiente código.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void buscarElemento(int a[], int size, int element_Busqueda);

int main()
{
    int n; // Variable que determinará el número de elementos del arreglo.
    int i; // Variable para recorrer el arreglo.
    int elemento;



    printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos del arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int array[n]; // Creamos un arreglo de enteros, el número de elementos del arreglo
    // será el número asignado a la variable 'n'.

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingresa el elemento numero %d del arreglo: ", (i+1) );
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Ingresa el elemento a buscar en el arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&elemento);

    buscarElemento(array, n, elemento);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void buscarElemento(int a[], int size, int element_Busqueda)
{
    int j;
    int hold1,hold2;


    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if(element_Busqueda == a[j])
        {
            hold1 = a[j];
            hold2 = j;
            printf("El elemento encontrado es %d y se encuentra en la posicion %d.",hold1,hold2);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿qué tal si ya puestos eliminas `hold1`y `hold2`? ¿Y si declaras `i` y `j` dentro del `for`? Ya que le presentas el ejercicio corregido puedes aprovechar para mostrarle más cosas a mejorar.